# Add new non-wordpress website under same domain in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, subdomain

Is it possible to add new non-wordpress website under same domain in Wordpress?

My domain is http://7deal.com/ and I want to access my non-wordpress website using http://7deal.com/merchant/. I already upload my new files and tried it and it display page can't be found.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main directory where your web files are stored you will just need to make a folder called "merchant". Then add all of your new website files in there.

NOTE: wordpress's `.htaccess` file may cause some issues depending on what the other website is!

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete or rename wordpress root .htaccess.